# Disable AMD graphics card and enabling Intel HD

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have a HP laptop with two graphic cards: the Intel HD4000 and the AMD 7700M.
My laptop stops booting showing the following message
[image]

Does anyone know, how I could disable the AMD card and use only the Intel?

Comment: Did it work before? I am not sure radeon is related to the problem.

Comment: Well, I had a 16.04. I updated the RAM adding 8GB. After that, it started acting up. I removed the RAM and still...
Eventually, switched to 18.04 to figure out the problem